# Linq EF6 adding multiple columns in a table from a list - Skips even rows

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

My application is MVC 5; I am trying to add multiple columns form a list into a table using:

```
var mylist = itemsToUpdate.Select(item => new
            {
                FirstName = item.FirstName,
                LastName = item.LastName,
                SNumber = item.SNumber
            }).ToList();
            
            foreach (var item in mylist)
            {
                var notification = new NotificationOld
                {
                    FirstName = item.FirstName,
                    LastName = item.LastName,
                    SNumber = item.SNumber
                };
                db.NotificationOlds.Add(notification);
             }
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get duplicates of row missing even number rows.

UPDATE:
The issue was in how I developed my SQL view by using:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dbo.LearnersOld.ID) AS SNumber
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Could you please add NotificationOld model and its corresponding table?